# Преобразуется ли все возвращаемые значения в ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Прошу заранее прощения за глупый вопрос, но хочу для себя прояснить такое дело. В книге (см. скрин) написано, что в методе действия любое возвращаемое значение преобразуется в тип ActionResult. И в качестве примера приводится возвращаемый тип string, который , по словам автора преобразуется автоматом в тип ContentResult. И так происходит с любым типом отличным от ActionResult и его потомков. Однако почитав про класс ContentResult я понял, что он годен только для типа string. Однако методы действия возвращают и int и double и bool и пр. И даже пользовательские типы. В связи с этим я не могу понять, все-таки преобразуются ли все типы отличные от ActionResult и его потомков в ContentResult или какой-то другой тип данных или нет ?? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Правда на английском. Собственно ответ:

> Notice that the return type is a  double and not a type that derives
>   from  ActionResult . This is perfectly acceptable. When ASP.NET MVC
>   calls that method and sees that the return type is not an ActionResult
>   , it automatically creates a  ContentResult containing the result of
>   the action method and uses that internally as the  ActionResult . One
>   thing to keep in mind is that the  ContentResult requires a string
>   value, so the result of your action method needs to be converted to a
>   string fi rst. To do this, ASP.NET MVC calls the  ToString method on
>   the result, using  InvariantCulture , before passing it to the 
>   ContentResult . If you need to have the result formatted according to
>   a specifi c culture, you should explicitly return a ContentResult
>   yourself.